# A starter need some tips and tricks

Tags: c++

This might be a very stupid question as it's frequently asked on the internet. But i'm new to the game development and i would like to learn C++ in creating 3D games. what software is good for such things? :) also a little tip and tricks would be nice if some of you experienced guys could lend out.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE Draganov! Your question is very likely to get closed: "How to get started" questions are not a good fit for this site. We expect questions that can be given a definite answer, check the [faq].

Answer (score 4):

This is the best link i can give you. It´s the best explenation i ever read.

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/08/04/I-want-to-be-a-game-developer.aspx

Comment: +1 because this link does have everything asked for in the question, and because I'm probably going to be spending a few hours just going through the many many useful resources linked to from there.

Comment: Thank you aswell. i would +1 if i could but don't have the amount of reputation needed. but i've been looking through and it looks very good :) thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

as a quick response to a very open question 
you need to decide why you want to learn these things

if it is to purely make games in your spare time why not have a look at unity3d

if it is to become a programmer / gamedeveloper 
you should first learn the very basics of c++ http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php or any other language you may choose.

after that you need to start thinking about which platforms you want to target and types of games you would like to make.

then i would start to consider your options in line with DirectX or openGL  but always keep the options open to things like XNA, monogame or other libraries

there are thousands of tutorials out there microsoft has plenty of DirectX tutorials, and reimers.net has some also

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already decided why i want this.

I've looke through the link and it was a very useful site :)

My target is strategy games. motsly and i would be interested in making some first person shooters. I know it sounds huge. at least for me but I'm ready to try.

XNA is fine with me. i've been thinking of making some 2D games to begin with just to get the feel. and thank you for your time :)